# Casting Object to generic interface type in Linq expression

Tags: c#, object, generics, interface, casting

This is a more generic question related to a previous one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193086/jsonserviceclient-call-from-list-of-generic-objects

I have dozens of classes, all of which implement the IReturn interface. For example:

```
public class GetDataRequest : IReturn<GetDataResponse>
{
    public string SomeQueryString { get; set; }
}
```

In another program (Used for testing) I am selecting these types from an external assembly using linq, then creating an instance and adding it to a list of object:

```
var DtoClasses = (from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                    where (typeof(IReturn)).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                    select Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
```

From thie list of objects a selection is made for which class requires testing. The trouble is that the method (Which I have no control over) that these objects will be fed into has an interface constraint of IReturn. Even though all of my objects do in fact implement that interface, there seems to be no way to imply this to the compiler.

My question is how would I take a generic object and cast it into one which impliments an interface? Assuming the object in question *does* already impliment the interface, even though it isn't implied by its current state.

Thanks much

Comment: `typeof(IReturn)` Does that compiles? It will if there is a non generic version of `IReturn` exist but we're not sure about that. Also not clear what you're asking for. [Is this you're asking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25207426/2530848) ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: It does. `(typeof(IReturn)).IsAssignableFrom(t)` evaluates to a boolean value.

Comment: @MarcelN. How sure are you? There is no type named `IReturn` in op's code. All he have is `IReturn<T>`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Indeed. I missed the generic interface.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Actually, a quick test shows that it does compile with a small change. Tested with something like `where (typeof(IComparable<>)).IsAssignableFrom(t)`. Of course, OP may have a non-generic `IReturn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`.Cast<IReturn>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) on your `IEnumerable`:

```
List<IReturn> DtoClasses = 
    (from t in assembly.GetTypes()
     where (typeof(IReturn)).IsAssignableFrom(t)
     select Activator.CreateInstance(t))
        .Cast<IReturn>()
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Note `Cast<T>` will throw an Exception if for some weird reason one of the returned objects doesn't implement `IReturn`, although that shouldn't happen in this case.

Comment: OK, so OP does have a non-generic IReturn interface after all. The question talks only about an IReturn<T>.

Comment: This does do exactly what I want. However it seems that the ServiceStack client is giving me trouble with the IReturn object. Having said that, though.. this answer is still correct for my question. Thanks